# Calculate the end date from start date and number of days in C

Tags: c, date, console-application

for the past few hours I've been trying to figure out how to write a programme in C to calculate the end date based on the start date and number of days. (I haven't found the forum for this exact problem, yet).
So let's say you input 27/1/2021 as the starting date and then 380 days. The programme should now calculate and show you the end date 11/2/2022.
I don't know how to move forward, the help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int day, month, year, numberDays;

int leapYear(int year) {
    return (year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0));
}

int monthYear[12] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

int main(void) {

    printf("Enter starting date: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &day, &month, &year);

    printf("Enter number of days: ");
    scanf("%d", &numberDays);

    leapYear(year);

    int wholeYears, rest;
    if (leapYear(year)) {
        wholeYears = numberDays / 366;
        rest = numberDays % 366;
    }
    else {
        wholeYears = numberDays / 365;
        rest = numberDays % 365;
    }
    int resultYears = year + wholeYears;
    int midDays = day + rest;
    int resultMonths;

    return 0;
}
```

I can't move any further. I'd need help.

Comment: Hint: January 32 --> February 1, since January only has 31 days.  So January 27 + 380 days is January 407.  Now normalize.

Comment: "then 380 days" --> what is the potential range of the addition?  +/- 1000, +/- 1000000?

Answer (score 2):

> So let's say you input 27/1/2021 as the starting date and then 380 days. The programme should now calculate and show you the end date 11/2/2022.

An easy approach is to use `mktime()` to bring a date into its standard range.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
  struct tm start = {.tm_year = 2021 - 1900, .tm_mon = 1 - 1, .tm_mday = 27,
      .tm_hour = 12};  // Midday to avoid DST issues.
  start.tm_mday += 380;
  printf("%d/%d/%d\n", start.tm_mday, start.tm_mon + 1, start.tm_year + 1900);
  time_t t = mktime(&start);
  printf("%d/%d/%d %s\n", start.tm_mday, start.tm_mon + 1, start.tm_year + 1900, 
      t == -1 ? "failed" : "OK");
}
```

Output

```
407/1/2021
11/2/2022 OK
```

---

Otherwise with discrete code, one is effectively re-writing the year/month/day portion of `mktime()`.

Comment: Good use of midday — that avoids potential problems with time zones changing between winter and summer (standard and daylight saving) time.

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is - I´m interested in doing so without any precoded library.

Comment: @W4nnaCryy Such conditions as "doing so without any precoded library" and other restrictions belong in the original post - else we have a moving target.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Good eye - I did leave out a comment about `.tm_hour = 12` to see how close folks look at code.   I'll add it.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I have one more question, please. It works allright when number of days in the input is <10 000 approximately. But after I'd say 10k it just adds to the days and months and years are unchanged. It really isn't something that bugs me, but just out of curiousity. Thanks anyways for help.

Comment: @W4nnaCryy 1) In those problem cases, is the return value from `mktime(&start) == -1`?  If so, code may have reached passed the ability of its `mktime()`.  2) What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to move forward, the help would be appreciated.

Add the 380 to `d` of `y, m, d`.  Maybe add some value to `m` in other cases.  Then perform basic range reductions.  There are 12 months to every year.  Month range [1...12].  There are 365*400 + 97 days every 400 years.  Day of the month is at least 1.

Last step is to handle a day outside the month range.
A simply, **though inefficient**, approach: test if the data is more than the days in that month.  If so subtract the days in that month and advance to the next month.

I left out some code details as OP's goal is some ideas to move forward.

```
#define DAYSPER400YEARS (365 * 400 + 97)
#define JANUARY 1
#define FEBRUARY 2
#define DECEMBER 12
#define MONTHPERYEAR 12

static int is_leap_year(long long year) {
  // If not divisible by 4 ...
  // If not divisible by 100 ...
  // If not divisible by 400 ...
}

static int days_per_month(long long year, int month) {
  static const signed char dpm[] = { 0, //
      31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
  if (month != FEBRUARY) {
    return ....;
  }
  return .... + is_leap_year(year);
}

/*
 * Bring a date into it primary range.
 * https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar
 * The year, month, day may be any value INT_MIN ... INT_MAX.
 * Return error flag.
 */
bool ymd_to_primary_range(int *year, int *month, int *day) {
  long long y = *year;
  y += *month / 12;
  *month %= 12; // month now in -11 to 11 range
  while (*month < JANUARY) {
    *month += MONTHPERYEAR;
    year--;
  }
  y += (*day / DAYSPER400YEARS) * 400;
  *day %= DAYSPER400YEARS;
  while (*day < 1) {
    *day += DAYSPER400YEARS;
    y -= 400;
  }
  int dpm;
  while (*day > (dpm = days_per_month(y, *month))) {
    *day -= dpm; 
    (*month)++;
    if (*month > ...) {
      *month -= ....;
      y++;
    }
  }
  if (y < INT_MIN) {
    *year = INT_MIN;
    return true;
  }
  if (y > INT_MAX) {
    *year = INT_MAX;
    return true;
  }
  *year = (int) y;
  return false;
}
```

Smaple

```
int main(void) {
  int y = 2021;
  int m = 1;
  int d = 27;
  d += 380;
  printf("Error: %d\n", ymd_to_primary_range(&y, &m, &d));
  printf("Date (dmy): %2d/%02d/%04d\n", d, m, y);
}
```

Output

```
Error: 0
Date (dmy): 11/02/2022
```